# Plot of probability of 1-year survival event vs. variable value? Would be derived from a Cox model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, biostatistics

I am hoping to plot the probability of a patient surviving to 1 year without progression (`status==0`) vs. the value of a continuous variable (`radiation.dose`). This would be based on a univariate cox proportional hazards model. I've Googled this and can't find anyone who has done this before.  What I imagine is similar axes to this logistic regression plot: [Logistic probability vs. variable](https://afit-r.github.io/public/images/analytics/logistic_regression/plot2-1.png)

Here is some sample code for you to work with:

```
library("survival")
require("survival")

days <- rpois(100, 365)
status <- rbinom(100,1,0.34)
radiation.dose <- sapply(status,function(x){ifelse(x==0,rnorm(1,80,20),rnorm(1,60,20))})

df<-data.frame(days,status,radiation.dose)
mod<-Surv(df$days,df$status)
cox.mod<-coxph(mod~radiation.dose,data=df)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just thinking out loud here, I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment for better formatting.

According to the help file on predict.coxph, "The survival probability for a subject is equal to exp(-expected)." So we can predict the survival probability

```
cox.pred<- exp(-predict(cox.mod, type = "expected"))
plot(radiation.dose, cox.pred)
```

[image: Predicted Probability of Survival]

Comment: Thanks for thinking through this with me! I think this looks like the right function. I'm far from a statistics expert, but I would have thought that since the predicted probabilities are based on an underlying mathematical model there wouldn't be so much variance in the probabilities. I guess I was expecting what looks like a curve sort of like that logistic regression plot I linked to. Does that make sense? What are your thoughts?

Comment: The way the data set is created means both survivors and non-survivors have a 1 sd overlap of treatment between 60 and 80. Status doesn't depend on days, so why are you doing cox at all? My understanding: There are 100 patients. Each patient receives a treatment dose between 0 and 140. Patients then makes a single followup at ~365 days and are either in remission (status = 1) or relapsed (status = 0). Higher doses are more likely to cause remission. I am assuming  relapse patients that present too early are likely to be misdiagnosed as in remission and that is how days should be incorporated?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Ron Jensen is incorrect. By simply calling the `predict` function without specifying the `newdata` argument, you are predicting the survival probability given the `radiation.dose` *and* the observed value of time. You can easily see this because there is no clear relationship in your plot, which has to be the case since you used a cox-regression model.

If you want to plot the survival probability at t as a function of a continuous variable based on a cox-model, you can instead use the `contsurvplot` package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=contsurvplot) I created. Using your example, you can do it like this:

```
library(survival)
library(contsurvplot)

set.seed(42)

days <- rpois(100, 365)
status <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.34)
radiation.dose <- sapply(status,function(x){ifelse(x==0, rnorm(1,80,20), rnorm(1,60,20))})

df <- data.frame(days,status,radiation.dose)
mod <- cox.mod<-coxph(Surv(days, status) ~ radiation.dose, data=df, x=TRUE)

plot_surv_at_t(time="days",
               status="status",
               variable="radiation.dose",
               data=df,
               model=cox.mod,
               t=365)
```

[image: contsurvplot]

By specifying `t = 365`, you're telling the `plot_surv_at_t` function to use the survival probability at 1 year.

Since there are no other independent variables in this cox model, this is equivalent to using:

```
vals <- seq(min(df$radiation.dose), max(df$radiation.dose), 1)

newdata <- data.frame(radiation.dose=vals,
                      days=365,
                      status=0)

p <- predict(cox.mod, type="surv", newdata=newdata)

plot(vals, p)
```

[image: base_r]

If there is no specific reason to use one value of time, I would however recommend to use *survival area plots* or *survival contour plots* instead, as described in detail in this preprint: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.04644.pdf